# Decrypting SAM hive after Windows 10 anniversary update?

Tags: passwords, windows, password-cracking, mimikatz

After a lot of frustration, I've finally cracked my local Windows 10 password using mimikatz to extract the proper NTLM hash.

In particular, samdump2 decrypted the SAM hive into a list of users with "blank" passwords:

```
samdump2 system sam -o out
```

I.e., `admin:1001:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::`

Conversely, mimikatz succeeded in outputting the proper NTLM hash:

```
mimikatz # lsadump::sam /system:C:\system /sam:C:\sam
```

I.e.,

```
RID  : 000003e9 (1001)
User : admin
  Hash NTLM: f1320e0960da374b88e40cffbec44885
```

The problem with mimikatz is that AVs flag it as malware the moment it gets download.

Are there other tools available that can run on Linux that may decrypt the SAM file properly after Windows 10 anniversary update?

Comment: Can't you simply whitelist that software in your AV?

Comment: @forest - Yes, I can. But I really want to be able to decrypt the SAM hive on my Kali box instead.

Comment: Are you just asking for a way to crack NTLM hashes on Kali Linux?

Comment: I can easily crack the NTLM hashes on Kali using john. However, conventional tools like samdump2 fails in decrypting the SAM hive to reveal the NTLM hashes. I'm looking for a substitute for samdump2 with support for Windows 10...

Comment: @user111854 why does it have to be specifically on Win 10? It sounds like you want to crack them on the same machine...

Comment: @FlorinCoada - Yes, I can crack them on the same machine (i.e., Windows 10). However, I'd rather not use mimikatz...

Comment: The question is valid. A predecessor step - open the SAM hive - is required before the NTLM hashes are available. Mimikatz can do this, but the question is looking for ways to open the SAM hive when not on the original Windows OS at all, sidestepping the need for mimikatz.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams - Thanks! This is exactly what I'm asking... If you know  where to look up the details of how the SAM hive is formatted / encrypted, I might be able to write a new tool. Where can I find this information, do you know that?

Comment: Boot Mimikatz from a USB PE environment or close Disk and use offline windows computer.

Answer (score 5):

[`secretsdump.py`](https://github.com/SecureAuthCorp/impacket/blob/master/examples/secretsdump.py) from [impacket](https://github.com/SecureAuthCorp/impacket) works. It ships with Kali as `impacket-secretsdump`. After extracting the `SAM` and `SYSTEM` hives from `Windows/System32/config`, you can use it like this:

`impacket-secretsdump -sam SAM -system SYSTEM LOCAL`