# Blank decrypted Windows 10 passwords

Tags: hash, password-cracking, windows-10, john-the-ripper

I'm getting hashes from Windows 10 SAM using samdump2, then pass this to John the Ripper, with the `--format=NT` and `--show` arguments, and get:

```
username::1001:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::

1 password hash cracked, 0 left
```

There is no password, Windows does not accept an empty password.  What am I doing wrong?

*This is translated by machine translation, there may be inaccuracies*

Comment: "There is no password" -- how do you know? Are you understanding the output correctly?

Comment: @schroeder I mean that the decrypted password is empty. ```username:[there should be a password here, right?]:1001:hash1:hash2:::```

Comment: I think you need to add the full command and output to your question (copy/paste the text and use the code formatting tool)

Comment: @schroeder I have corrected the question. I didn't want to show hashes, I think they are significant, but after reading some articles it became clear that they are empty. Why is this happening? And how can you get passwords now, having the ```/Windows/System32/config``` folder?

Comment: You have not added what I asked you to add ... you don't need to show the hashes, but  as I said, you need to show the commands and the outputs

Comment: And I think you are looking for this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183891/decrypting-sam-hive-after-windows-10-anniversary-update

Comment: @schroeder impacket-secretsdump helped me get the correct hashes, thanks!